# What is : in php?

Tags: php

I made an error in my routes.php in laravel and typed `:` instead of `::`

```
Route:get('about','PagesController@about');
Route:get('contact','PagesController@contact');
```

and I got an error message `Label 'Route' already defined`

Just curious what this means...

Comment: Sorry guys Routes was a typo, and I know about static methods...

Comment: So the single colon in your example is not a typo?

Comment: No  @samrap it's the question, i think it's answered by CollinD, I ll accept when the system lets me...

Comment: I'm curious, where did you come across this example? Must have been a typo. As @max pointed out, you cannot call a  method using a goto

Comment: I just wrote by mistake the first  `Route:get `, and it actually worked... The error occurred when I added a second Route...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've discovered `label`s! They are a largely outdated and generally discouraged language construct that allows jumping around code via `goto` statements, as well as some others depending on language.

Example:

```
if (!array_key_exists('data', $_GET)) { goto hell; }
echo $_GET['data'] . " is the data I received.";

hell:
die("Erorr. . . or we finished. Who knows?");
```

There's some (semi-legitimate) functionality that can be implemented however. That said, still not a good practice:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 999; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < 999; $j++) {
    for ($k = 0; $k < 999; $k++) {
      if ($someCondition)
        goto EndOfAllTheLoops; //Look, we broke out of ALL three loops!
    }
  }
}

EndOfAllTheLoops:
echo "We made it out!"
```

See PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Comment: I don't think this is what OP was asking about, his example is straight from the Laravel framework which does not use `goto` and uses `Route::method` to define routes for the application

Comment: However, you cannot call a method by `EndOfAllTheLoops:foo` which makes it more about understanding the intent of the code.

Comment: It seems like OP identified the error pretty quickly and was instead curious what the actual effect of the single colon is. @Orestiss please clarify

Comment: @CollinD you are right... sorry guys if the question was ambiguous

Comment: This answer isn't complete without [a relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/292/) (edit: realized they even put it in the PHP docs - I'm a dummy)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Route`, not `Routes`. (Note, there should not be an S)

Comment: That's what I've stated. The original post has been edited since I answered as it has ```Routes```. My poor eyesight missed the single colon though which also doesn't help with the syntax issue.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I`m tired

Comment: It's ok. This doesn't address the question as asked anyway @KA_lin

Comment: It addressed the original question which since been edited.